# Boot from Terminal in Recovery Mode

Tags: terminal, startup, filevault

Laptop: Macbook Pro 2015 with macOS Mojave freshly upgraded from High Sierra and active FileVault.

Issue: After Mojave installation I see the prohibit sign and can't boot as usual

What I did so far: I figured out the issue is about FileVault and "missing/lost user". I unlocked the FileVault from Recovery Mode and retrieved my files, now I want to try to boot regularly but I don't know the command.

Question: How to boot from Terminal directly? I mean without rebooting.

Comment: Recovery mode boots from a different partition usually, so I doubt that you can boot into a full system without a reboot. Why do you want to skip the reboot step?

Comment: Because if I reboot I'll have the prohibit sign.

Edit: This prevents the normal boot and it's caused by and error creating the user, probably caused by the apfs conversion of a filevault enabled disk during upgrade.

Comment: If you already retrieved your files: wouldn't it be simpler to just reinstall everything?

Comment: You have to fix this either from Mojave Recovery Mode or a thumb drive/external drive with (a full-fledged) Mojave installed. Or simply a fresh install & import your files&folders... - one solution in Recovery Mode: trying to revert FV...

Comment: @klanomath Yes, my target now is to unlock FileVault again then try a revert but I think that it's not so easy: the diskutil apfs decryptVolume command has been updated on macOS 10.13.2 to require additional authentication. Have you direct experience about that?

Comment: @nohillside Actually I know that I can reinstall everything but I want to get deeper about this topic and get experience about it.